# Analyze article, find city in specified language

Tags: elasticsearch, data-analysis, tagging

I want analyze article for contained cities and regions (europe, asia ...).

But i need to do it for specified language (czech for example).

Searching every word in document seems to be not very efective.
I want to ask what technology/process do you suggest to use?

Comment: how can you guarantee you've found all possible words of interest if you don't actually look at all words?

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to do something like foreach every word in document

Comment: Elasticsearch uses an inverted index, it does not use a foreach. But if you want to make the index smaller you may extract cities an regions on a special field, and index only that one.